# wkhtmltopdf - Chinese characters slanting

Tags: ruby, wkhtmltopdf, non-latin

I tried converting http://book.kanunu.org/book4/10406/231373.html to PDF.

I used the following command:
`wkhtmltopdf --encoding gbk http://book.kanunu.org/book4/10406/231373.html test.pdf`

And I got the following output:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1232162/3973254/d67340e6-27e5-11e4-9b30-a7df42e0bc41.png

As you can see the characters slant. I tested out more websites and realized that this happens only for Chinese and Japanese characters. Does anyone know why that is the case?